# In C#, is it possible for an object to have a data member that by default references itself?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to create an account system, where accounts have a "primary account" reference.  The reference will indicate the primary account for this object.  When created, I would like it to, by default, be set to be it's own primary account.

Is this going to cause an error?

How exactly do I write that?  Would it use the word this?

I'm newer to OOP, thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you mean **users** have a primary account?

Comment: No, I'm actually linking accounts to one account.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like

```
public class Account
{
    private Account _parent;
    public Account Parent
    {
        get { return _parent ?? this; }
        set { _parent = value; }
    }
}
```

Would help?

Comment: +1: Funny that we all wrote it differently, great minds think alike:)

Comment: But yours is the best looking one if you ask me.

Comment: +1 Yep, pretty terse and compact, though most would struggle with what the `??` operator actually does. :)

Comment: @Krof Drakula ReSharper to the rescue! ReSharper automatically suggests such things. This is kind of "interactive learning" for me, which is pretty neat.

Comment: True, if available. Though it still rests upon the developer to understand why ReSharper suggested it in the first place.

Comment: @Krof Dakula: Do you think the `x ? y : z` is easier to understand? Either way I think both are great operators and everyone programming `C#` should learn them if you ask me. Of course you shouldn't over use them, as with everything :).

Comment: I'm saying that `??` and the ternary operators are awesome, just unheard of/unexplained/used blindly by most programmers. It would be awesome if they got to know them.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this out, but something like this should work:

```
public class MyObject {
  protected MyObject myObjectInstance;
  public MyObject MyObjectInstance {
    get { return (myObjectInstance == null)? this: myObjectInstance;
    set { myObjectInstance = value; }
  }
}
```

This way you have a property called `MyObjectInstance` that does exactly what you want it to.

Comment: +1: Funny that we all wrote it differently, great minds think alike:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would should be able to do this by writing your property like

```
private Account _primaryAccount;
public Account PrimaryAccount
{
    get
    {
        if(_primaryAccount == null)
            return this;
        return _primaryAccount;
    }
    set { _primaryAccount = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be more correct to use the value `null` to indicate the `Account` instance has no parent.

Your account structure is a [tree structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) (one of the most common patterns in programming). In a tree structure, a node with no parent is considered a root element. In .NET, the clearest way for a node to say "I have no parent" is to return `null` from a "parent" property.

There is nothing directly wrong with having a property return the current instance as its value, but it is somewhat confusing and moves away from the conventions expected in a tree structure.

Comment: Although it may appear to be, this actually isn't following a tree structure in the conventional sense.  The accounts will never form a chain of any sort... there will only ever be a parent and children.  If a user chooses to target an account that already has a primary other than itself, it will in fact use the target accounts primary instead.  The reason for my choice of referencing itself as the parent is because in many places I will be comparing two account's parents.  If I were to use null, I would then have to add an if statement to check for that, and then use the...

Comment: account that I had just checked anyway.  So it made more sense, in this odd case, to have it reference itself as it's own, if it were possible... simply to cut out writing that same if statement over and over again.  Thank you though, that would have been helpful otherwise!